# Could we be biased toward positive integers throughout mathematics?

Tags: integers, axioms

What I am getting at is that throughout math we have to refer to things using positive integers. In a a polynomial, we talk about the first (that is, the "positive oneth") term and so forth. There is no such thing as the "negative oneth" term of a polynomial. Even in 2*3 = 6, I don't know what you call the two, but maybe it is also referred to as the first term or something.
Anyway, perhaps this underlying "bias" towards positive integers is why we consider the product of two negatives to be a positive -- if not that, some other intuition that we might not have if we had objects to represent equations etc. that were not based on positive integers.

Forgive me if this is a dumb question but I have thought about this for a while and I have some experience with mathematics.

Comment: Are we "biased" ? Obviously yes; the counting numbers are the first "mathematical" objects we encounter, from the beginning of the language learning process. We use them everyday to count things.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: and if so, does that perhaps have bearing on basic things like the product of two negatives?

Comment: If you think a pro-positive bias made us say the product of two negative numbers is positive, why do you think we say their sum is negative, or that the product would be negative if there were three of them?

Comment: The more "abstract" types of numbers are constructed in a way to match (if possible) with intuition and to satisfy consistency and co-existence (where possible) with already existing objects.

Comment: @J.G.: is it intuitive to u that negative numbers can "influence" other numbers to change sign but positives cannot? this post is not specifically about negative numbers but whether math is so heavily dependent in its concepts and notation on positive integers that this MIGHT affect our entire thinking about math.

Answer (score 0):

An essential building block of mathematics are the natural numbers, which arose by the universal need to count. Negative counts make non sense. [Please don't bombard me with comments explaining how negative counts can be given sense.] So the bias towards positive is obvious.

The case of the product of two negatives is certainly not related to this bias. It comes from the necessity to have a coherent multiplication operation when acting on negatives.

$$(-1)(1-1)=(-1)+(-1)(-1)=0$$ demands $$(-1)(-1)=1.$$

---

Side remark: the Python language smartly defines a list indexing system such that $0$ and positives denote the *first* elements, while negatives allow access to the *last* ones.

Comment: so you would say there should be no definition of ,say, a series that has terms other than integer terms?

Comment: @releseabe Sequences that run in both directions are often considered. You might want to try working out the last few Fibonacci numbers before $F_0$ to see what happens.

Comment: @releseabe: Please don't bombard me with comments explaining how negative counts can be given sense.